# How to check if chrome extensions is installed

Tags: powershell, google-chrome, ps

I need to check if the Chrome extension is installed via Powershell.

What i have now is this:

```
function Get-ChromeExtension {
    param (
        [string]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    )

    Get-ChildItem "\\$ComputerName\c$\users\*\appdata\local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\*\*\manifest.json" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | % {
        $path = $_.FullName
        $_.FullName -match 'users\\(.*?)\\appdata' | Out-Null
        Get-Content $_.FullName -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json | select @{n='ComputerName';e={$ComputerName}}, @{n='User';e={$Matches[1]}}, Name, Version, @{n='Path';e={$path}}
    }
}

Get-ChromeExtension | ? name -notmatch '__msg_' | sort user, name, {[version]$_.version}
```

It returns extensions just fine.
And I need to make conditions to find which extensions are and are not installed.

Something like this:

```
$extensions = Get-ChromeExtension | ? name -notmatch '__msg_' | sort user, name, {[version]$_.version}

if($extensions -like "NameOfPlugin")
{
   #DO SOMETHING
}
```

I guess I cannot convert it to string this easily. Is there a different method of how can I find if "Name" contains a specific string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `name` property in this way:

```
if($extensions.name -like "NameOfPlugin")
{
   #DO SOMETHING
}
```

You can also check it with `-match` or `-contains`.